# What difference does rooting hormone make when propagating plants from cuttings?

Tags: propagation, rooting-hormone, cuttings

What difference does rooting hormone make when propagating plants from cuttings?  I have have been successful with and without it, but I would like to know for example, if it affects the speed or health of the growth.

Comment: This is a more general question than my one here about simply using "willow water" as a hormone for propagation (an organic alternative)... http://gardening.stackexchange.com/questions/2926/efficacy-of-willow-water-for-improving-propagation-of-cuttings

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There is a very full description of the various types of hormone rooting compound [here](http://www.oakleafgardening.com/glossary-terms/hormone-rooting-compound/).

As already pointed out, it is supposed to stimulate root formation; I have tried using it on  cuttings a couple of times, but haven't fond it effective; in fact, if anything, some of the cuttings would probably have done better without it.

According to the New Encyclopedia of Gardening Techniques (Royal Horticultural Society):

> . . . . If the stem cutting is propagated from a
>   healthy plant and at the correct season, then the use of such hormones
>   is usually of no advantage whatsoever.
>
> The concentration of hormone applied  to induce root formation is not the best concentration to cause root development.
>
> By applying the hormone the roots are induced to form, but if they
>   emerge and come into contact with the hormone.... this
>   may cause the roots to die off.

Answer (score 7):

It is meant to stimulate root growth - in particular to stimulate the creation of roots.

I've only tried it on peach cuttings so far, and haven't don't a comparison with/without. These had mixed results but for other reasons - first time it was the wrong time of year, and the second time most of the cuttings were too immature.